# AngularJS / Firebase storage getDownloadURL working example

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying hard to store a file in Firebase storage, and apparently it is working.

But, when I want to fetch the URL for the file so that the user can view / download the file, I run into problem.

My file is an image file and the purpose is to display it on the page.

Here is my attempt:

```
var url = spaceRef.getDownloadURL()
    .then(function(url){
        return url;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        $scope.errMsg = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
    });
```

But I am stuck and don't know how to display it.

Can somebody post an answer with a working example of fetching the image URL and display it in the `<img>` tag?

Thanks in advance.

### edit:

here is the documentation for the this function
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Comment: @Grant: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, very helpful as usual